# matching comment environments, no longer able to comment out text

Tags: errors, verbatim, comments

I have a long LaTeX document and I am trying to comment out lines of text using `\begin{comment} text \end{comment}`  and while compiling the document I have the interpreter giving out:

```
<recently read> \@savsf 
l.429 \end{comment}
? q
```

Prompting me to put some input, I know only press <kbd>q</kbd>. Now when I add new matching comment environments, the text does not get commented out but remains there.

Is it possible that I have unpaired tags, or that there are interleaved environments conflicting? And how can I find the problem and untangle it?

(UPDATE: the text I try to comment out had inside it commented sections. When these sections are removed by cutting them out the comment environment works. Using the package **verbatim**)

Comment: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. A [little known markup](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/stackexchange-secret-pages/1002#1002) is enclosing keyboard strokes with `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`.

Comment: I don't have much advice except some quick googling suggests this error comes up when you are in vertical mode in the wrong place (e.g. the \end{comment}).  But this is a case where trying to construct a minimal example may actually lead you directly to the problem, since the problem is almost certainly something mismatched.  (i.e. first construct a copy of the file with only that comment block and see if the error persists.  Then start commenting out parts of that using %. etc.)

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear which package you are using, nor the exact format of your code, but the `comment` package documentation says this:

> The opening and closing commands
>   should appear on a line of their own.

So your example should work if you code it like this:

```
\begin{comment}
text
\end{comment}
```

I believe this is because the package actually scans the input file looking for `\end{comment}` in column 1...

Comment: indeed it does (look in column 1); we would really need the original code to provide coherent advice.  note that \begin/\end{comment} won't work from within another command, either.